# Is $a^{p^n-1}=1\mod p$ where $p$ is prime number and $1<a<p-1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is $a^{p^n-1}=1\mod p$ where $p$ is prime number and $1\lt a\lt p-1$?

When $n=1$ by little fermats theorem theorem it is true. But i can't justify generaly whether it is correct or not. But when i give number for $p=5$ and $a=3$ , it is working.

Comment: $$(p-1)|(p^n-1)$$

Comment: using that what can i say.

Comment: Note that if $p^n-1 = m(p-1)$ then $a^{p^n - 1} = a^{m(p-1)} = (a^m)^{p-1}$.

Comment: You probably mean $1 \leq a \leq p-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using directly lab's excellent hint and Fermat's Little theorem (since $\;(a,p)=1\;$):

$$a^{p^n-1}=\left(a^{p-1}\right)^k=1^k=1\pmod p$$

where $\;k=p^{n-1}+p^{n-2}+\ldots+p+1\;$

Answer (score 0):

Since $a$ is nonzero modulo $p$, you obtain an equivalent equation multiplying by $a$. That is, it's enough to prove that $a^{p^n} = a$.

Fermat's Little Theorem tells you that if you define $F \colon \mathbf{Z}_p \to \mathbf{Z}_p$ by $F(a) = a^p$, then $F = \mathrm{id}$. To prove the equation, note that it can be restated as $(F \circ F \circ \dots \circ F)(a) = a$, where $F$ is composed with itself $n$ times.